# Fitting several d3.js examples on the same page: CSS classes with svg.append?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to merge two d3.js examples into a single html file, which I have put in [dropbox](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17949100/d3.html).  For reference, the two examples are [A](http://bl.ocks.org/1062544) and [B](http://bl.ocks.org/3846051).

In order to merge the two files, I had to use CSS classes and call them from javascript.  The CSS:

```
circle.a { stroke: #fff; }
circle.b { fill: none; stroke-width: 1.5px; }
```

Unfortunately, I am having trouble calling CSS classes from D3:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
svg.append("svg:circle[class=a]")
...
var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
svg.append("circle[class=b]")
```

More practically, I may like to have several d3 images running on the same page.  It could be in a different way than above.

@Moderators: Feel free to move to a different part of StackExchange that may fit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
 svg.append("svg:circle").attr("class","circle.a")
```

You can also define attributes specific to this operation with the `attr` function without having to create a CSS file (but it easily gets messy

Comment: svg.append("svg:circle").attr("class","a")

Comment: In the end, one used v3.0 and the other used v1.25.  I will find the deprecated functions or probably just start over.